# How do I deactivate a Portal User in Apex Code?

Tags: customer-portal

Is it possible to deactivate a Customer Portal user using Apex?

Answer (score 9):

```
// Assume cIds is a list of Contacts whose users we wish to deactivate
List<User> usersToUpdate = new List<User>();
for(User u : [Select u.Id, u.IsActive, u.IsPortalEnabled from User u where u.ContactId    in :cIds]){
    if(u.IsActive || u.IsPortalEnabled ){
        u.IsActive = false;
        u.IsPortalEnabled = false;
        usersToUpdate.add(u);
    }
}

if (usersToUpdate.size()>0){
    update usersToUpdate;
}
```

The above snippet might help.

Comment: i got the error testing through postman.."Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00590000001g7hXAAQ; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Cannot de-activate self: Active: [IsActive]"

Comment: Try deactivating a user other than the one you're logged in as! I just verified that Mohith's code works just fine.

Comment: Thanks @metadaddy for veryfying .Had no time to respond :-(

Comment: If that answers your question then please mark as answered .

Comment: Isn't setting IsPortalEnabled to false enough? Or should it always be accompanied with IsActive = false; as well?

Comment: set IsPortalEnabled only can work, IsActive will be automatically set to false too. but it's safer and no harm to set both flags. I encounter the situation that deactivation takes minutes to take into effect. No idea why :(.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava do you know if there is a way to delete the associated Contact record for the Portal User you are deactivating via Apex? I've tried firing a queueable job once updating the user but it doesn't look like the deactivating completes in time. There doesn't seem to be anything on the Contact record I can trigger off of either.

Comment: Can you ask as another query?

Answer (score 6):

This question was asked and last answered back in 2013.  In 2021, it seems that  attempting to update User.isActive in the same update operation that sets User.isPortalEnabled will actually cause the update operation to fail.

When you set User.isPortalEnabled = false SFDC will automatically set User.isActive to false and User.ContactId to null, which is what we want.

So, for a collection of Contact ID's named "contactIds" that are related to User records you would like to disable:

```
List<User> usersToDisable = [select id from User where ContactId in :contactIds];
for (User u : usersToDisable) {
  u.isPortalEnabled = false;
}
update usersToDisable;
```