# Disabling community user in community Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, user

I would like to allow community user to disable another community user in community Visualforce UI.

From this post: [How do I deactivate a Portal User in Apex Code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17389/how-do-i-deactivate-a-portal-user-in-apex-code), the answer suggests to set user.IsPortalEnabled as false in order to disable a user. However it gives error when I implement the code in Visualforce page's controller

```
public PageReference deleteUser() {
    System.debug('targetUser: '+targetUser);

    User u = [SELECT Id, Contactid, IsActive, IsPortalEnabled FROM User WHERE Id = :targetUser];
    Id contactid = u.contactid;
    u.IsActive = false;
    u.IsPortalEnabled = false;
    update u;

    removeContact(contactid);

    String[] url = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl().split('\\?');
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(url[0] + '?tab=User Management');     

    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
```

It gives error when I visit the VF inside the community:
`Error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 005S0000004hHPuIAM; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []`

I have tried the code with system admin account, it works. I can't understand why it doesn't work when it is called by community user. Apex code should have system level access right? I have explicitly added `without sharing` to the above class, it still doesn't work.

Also I understand the difference between disabling and deactivating a user. I want to disable it as I would like to delete its linked contact as well. If I comment out `u.IsPortalEnabled = false;`, it passes `update u;` but it does not allow me to remove the contact.

Answer (score 5):

Partner Community profile has permission "`Delegated External User Administrator`" and they can create disable community users.

However, You cannot disable one community user by login other customer community user because Community profile does not provide "`Manage User`" or "`Delegated External User Administrator`" permission on profile. [You can check this implementation guide for community.](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf)

Still if you want to do this, I would suggest to create a record in Custom object which will track which user needs to be disabled and then you can use scheduler which will read this record and disable community user every 1 hour.

Comment: Why can community user creates another community users, but cannot disable it....

Comment: That's good point, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, but I still somehow don't understand. I do not have `Delegated External User Administrator` permission enabled as I only got community login license. However I can allow community user to create another community through Apex code. Why can't I disable community user instead? According to my understanding on your explanation, my community user should neither create nor disable other community users.

Comment: I have a user that does have the "Delegated External User Administrator" permission and still cannot disable partner users.