# Deactivating/detaching a Community User( from the Contact) - System not recognising the deactivation

Tags: community

I am trying to deactivate a user associated with a Contact and create a new user for that contact. I am getting a 'PORTAL_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS_FOR_CONTACT' error inspite of deactivating the necessary fields on the User object.Please help..

```
//Getting Contact for an id  
List<Contact> portalContactIds = [Select Email from Contact where id =:conid];  
//Getting associating users for that contact  
List<User>deactivateUsers = [Select isActive,isPortalEnabled from User where contactid in :portalContactIds]  
//Deactivating users  
for(User usr:deactivateUsers)  
{  
   usr.isActive = false;  
   usr.IsPortalEnabled = false;  
}   
update deactivateUsers;  

List<User> usrList  = new List<User>();  
for(Contact con: portalContactIds)  
    {  
//Creating new users to associate with the Contact  
User usr = new User( Email=con.Email,   
                    isActive = true,  
                    UserName=con.Email,  ContactId = con.id,  
                    );  
        usrList.add(usr);  
}  
//Getting error 'PORTAL_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS_FOR_CONTACT' at this line  
insert usrList;
```

A strange behaviour that i noticed is that, if i comment the 'insert' statement and execute only update once and then uncomment the 'insert' in the 2nd run, it all works fine.
This makes me think that it is taking a while for the update to reflect, i tried introducing a delay after update, but it did not help!!

Comment: Is this something you have to do in code?  Can your users do it in the UI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deactivate a Portal User in Apex Code?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17389/how-do-i-deactivate-a-portal-user-in-apex-code)

Comment: @NickCook: This is not a duplicate since the issue i am facing is different. I am able to deactivate, but somehow the system doesn't recognise it as a deactivation, not sure why. The deactivation should happen from a trigger in apex

Comment: Have you tried clearing the ContatId field on the User record?

Comment: I will not be allowed to do it. It is a read-only field on the User object

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue twice in my projects. System does recognize the deactivation but not immediately. It is not same as isActive = false. System takes few seconds time to completely deactivate the user. You can run a query and after the Update and see that the isPortalEnabled will still be set to True.

I always flag the User record during deactivation. Then run a scheduled job every 5 min to create new users with same contact associated.